# Pressing <shift> + ~ on QWERTY pt-pt layout, on Google Chrome Element Inspector, opens definitions in the console

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, keyboard

This is a rather weird bug or annoyance.

When I'm writting in the console, on the Element Inspector, and I click `<shift> + ~` (to write the `^`  character), the definitions show up.

I have an Asus W3000 keyboard+mouse wireless set, with QWERTY pt-pt layout.

My chrome version is the latest version (39.0.2171.99m as of today), and this only started happening on this version.

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium x64 with the drivers properly installed and everything working fine.

This is rather annoying since I can't write important things, like bitshifting operations and regular expressions.
When I click on the key combination, the carret/promp is placed at the beggining and the next times it writes `^` *only and only* at the beggining and *only* if the carret/prompt is at the beggining.

Is there ANYTHING to disable this *very* annoying behaviour?

---

This also happens on the latest release, updated today, to version 40.0.2214.91 m.

Comment: happens here too

Comment: @dippas You know anything to disable this?

Comment: I tried to search and all but couldn't figure out.. I'll let you know if I'll find a solution

Comment: @dippas Thanks. I've checked on the options and there is no such thing. I believe that there isn't even a shortcut to open the definitions!